# log4net xmlconfigurator.configure needs to use the dll embedded xml file

Tags: c#, .net, windows, log4net

I am creating a console application (exe) and trying to log the errors using log4net. If I give any of the below commands in the main method the logger works fine:

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(@"filepath\log4net.config"));
```

or

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("..\\..\\log4net.config",FileMode.Open))
              { XmlConfigurator.Configure(fs); }
```

But I need to have the log4net.config file separately. So my question is - how do I refer to the log4net.config file (which is embedded in the exe) in my main method to enable the logger, so that I don't need to have the separate log4net config file other than the exe file? It makes easier for moving exe alone to other machine.

Note: log4net.config file is an embedded resource in the exe.

Answer (score 4):

To load the config from an embedded file, the best way is to use the [overload of Configure that takes a stream](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_Config_XmlConfigurator_Configure_7.htm), for example:

```
 var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); // or GetEntryAssembly()
 var resourceName = "log4net.config";

 using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
 {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure(stream);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your correction & response. I used the above code But am getting **Null** value for stream if i give 'var resourceName = "log4net.config";' Or **system.io.unmanagedmemorystream** for stream if i give 'var resourceName = "assemblyname.log4net.config";'.  So do have any idea that am done anything wrong.

Comment: You will have to change that to the actual resource name

Comment: Yes i have config file with name as log4net in this project

Comment: You can make a call to `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();` to get all the resource names.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked for me (both first & second suggestion).

Comment: Note: Still stream has value as **system.io.unmanagedmemorystream** but that's not a problem here...